# assembly is not found during initialize component for UserControl with DocumentViewer

Tags: .net, wpf, assemblies, wpf-4.5

I have a wpf 4.5 application where I want to use a document viewer in an attempt at creating my own report viewer ([based on this example](http://www.nullskull.com/a/1442/wpf-report-engine-part-3.aspx)).  But if I add a DocumentViewer to one of my user controls I get the following error during the **initialize component** for the usercontrol.

> Could not load file or assembly 'PresentationUI.Aero2,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or
>   one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

But as you can see from the screen shot of my references, this file is included:

[image]

I get this error even if the document viewer is empty.

### What I tried:

1. I used blend4 to edit the default style of the DocumentViewer Control.  I removed all style references that used control parts from the Aero2 library.  I even tried using an empty style.  But the error still appears.
2. I created both a wpf 4 and wpf 4.5 empty solution and added a document viewer to the main window.  THe projects both run without error and they both run without adding a reference to any Aero Presentation dll.
3. I tried to add a new wpf project to the solution where I am getting the error.  IN that project I added a documentviewer to the main window, and the same error was generated.  It seems to be solution specific.

### Problem

Can someone help me figure out why I am getting this error, or how to remove the control's dependency on this Aero2 dll.

thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How I solved this:

- creating a new blank solution
- then adding the existing projects from the "old" solution to the new solution. (for me my solution had 5 projects in it so I had to add them all).
- I then built and ran the new solution.

This solved the error and there are no references to Aero2 in any of my projects.

I am not sure why this fixed it, But I am glad that it did.